# Where does Visual Studio store the Debug Start Action Start External Program

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, csproj, project-settings, project-properties

In Visual Studio, when you go to the Project Properties, Click Debug, and set the Start Action "Start external program", where does Visual Studio save that setting? as far as I can tell, it does not store it in the csproj file as I would expect. When other developers clone the project from git, this setting is not set.

Comment: this is stored in the user file (.suo - solution user options)

Comment: I guess I could add the file to git, then put it in the .gitIgnore file... Thanks.

Comment: Should that be the answer to this?

Comment: Yes, but all I have the ability to do is up vote the comment.